# FTPS (TLS/SSL) from Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an FTP server which only accepts connections through running FTPS (explicit FTP over TLS). I need to be able to connect to this using a Ruby on Rails app.

**Does anybody know of a method to do this?** I have tried the `Net::FTP` library but this does not appear to support FTPS connections.

Answer (score 8):

How about using `Net::FTPTLS` ?

Comment: Where is this found? How can I install it? I couldn't figure it out by searching for it on Google.

Comment: @adamjford, It should come with your Ruby.  On my box, it's in `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftptls.rb`.  On yours, it may be somewhere else.  Wherever it is, `require 'net/ftptls'` ought to work.

Comment: Wondering where it went in ruby 1.9

Comment: @mat : Have you tried the ftpfxp gem? It has a FTPFXPTLS class that wraps TLS over the standard Net::FTP class.

Comment: I actually made a small one which works for 1.9, but only in passive mode (only needed passive) : https://gist.github.com/1039994

Answer (score 5):

Since Ruby 2.4, TLS over FTP has been available with `Net::FTP`... this has caused gems like double-bag-ftps to become archived and all your google searches to yield outdated answers.

If you can do explicit FTP over TLS (Connects to FTP normally, then issues a command AUTH TLS to switch to TLS Mode), then great... that *should* be able to use Ruby's Net::FTP out of the box by just passing `{ssl: true}` in the options.

Implicit FTP over TLS (runs over TLS from the get-go) does *not* work out of the box, however, and you must override `Net::FTP`'s connection method to establish an SSL socket and then optionally send commands to the FTP server.

Inidka K posted a Github Gist, but since those are bad form (can go stale), I've posted my version that works against a ShareFile Implicit FTP setup (which seems to only support Implicit FTP):

```
require 'net/ftp'

class ImplicitFtp < Net::FTP
  FTP_PORT = 990

  def connect(host, port = FTP_PORT)
    synchronize do
      @host = host
      @bare_sock = open_socket(host, port)
      begin
        ssl_sock = start_tls_session(Socket.tcp(host, port))
        @sock = BufferedSSLSocket.new(ssl_sock, read_timeout: @read_timeout)
        voidresp
        if @private_data_connection
          voidcmd("PBSZ 0")
          voidcmd("PROT P")
        end
      rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Net::OpenTimeout
        @sock.close
        raise
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in your code:

```
ftp_options = {
  port:    990,
  ssl:      true,
  debug_mode: true, # If you want to see what's going on
  username: FTP_USER,
  password: FTP_PASS
}
ftp = ImplicitFtp.open(FTP_HOST, ftp_options)
puts ftp.list
ftp.close
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I done something like this with Implicit/Explicit FTPS, I used double-bag-ftps gem that I patched to support reuse of ssl session. It's a requirement for a lot of ftps servers.

I put the code on github here : https://github.com/alain75007/double-bag-ftps

Answer (score 3):

Support for implicit FTPS was merged into [`ruby/net-ftp`](https://github.com/ruby/net-ftp) in January 2022 (in [this PR](https://github.com/ruby/net-ftp/pull/9/files)).  If you want to make use of this straight away, you can include the latest version directly in your Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'net-ftp', :require => 'net/ftp'
```

Then you just need:

```rb
options = {
  ssl: true,
  port: 990,
  implicit_ftps: true,
  username: "your-user",
  password: "*********",
  debug_mode: true
}

Net::FTP.open("yourhost.com", options) do |ftp|
  ftp.list.map{ |f| puts f }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Implicit FTPS, please try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dcparker/85632).

For Explicit FTPs, you can use the ruby gem `ftpfxp`.

Comment: Running `gem install ftpfxp` produces `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FormatException)
    ftpfxp-0.0.4 has an invalid value for @cert_chain`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I figured out how to get it running locally, but am having issues getting it to work on Heroku.  That's a bit of a departure from this question, so I've created a new one:

[Heroku with FTPTLS - Error on SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255005/heroku-with-ftptls-error-on-ssl-connection)

```
require 'net/ftptls'
ftp = Net::FTPTLS.new()
ftp.passive = true
#make sure you define port_number
ftp.connect('host.com', port_number)
ftp.login('Username', 'Password')
ftp.gettextfile('filename.ext', 'where/to/save/file.ext')
ftp.close
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an ftps solution using double-bag-ftps

[double-bag-ftps](https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps)