# ruby ftp over explicit TLS/SSL in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FTPS (TLS/SSL) from Ruby on Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024340/ftps-tls-ssl-from-ruby-on-rails-app)

Hi, folks,

How can I connect from Ruby (RoR) to ftps (ftp over explicit TLS/SSL in Ruby on Rails) host?

Googling didn't provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: 
 we can use `lftp` utility, then call it from ruby.

```
lftp -f file_with_command
```

where in 'file_with_command' file we specify :

```
lftp -u %s,%s %s
get '%s'
exit
```

where `%s` will be replaced with username, password, hostname, file to get correspondingly.